# C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, namespaces

Seriously getting on my nerves. This code was working just fine earlier, I restarted the IDE (Visual Studio 2010) and now suddenly the code goes bonkers on me. The error log is huge, and I have no idea what's causing it as the code seems to be pretty much correct.

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  uicont.cpp
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Many more, but I assume this is what's causing the error. Here is the source code for the files that are having the most problems.

**Mage/GUI/UIContext.h**

```
#include <OGRE/OgreString.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreOverlay.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreOverlayManager.h>

#include <vector>

#include <Mage/GUI/Frame.h>

#ifndef __H_MAGE_UICONTEXT
#define __H_MAGE_UICONTEXT

namespace Mage {
    class UIContext {
    public:
        UIContext();
        ~UIContext();

        GUI::Frame* createFrame(Ogre::String, Ogre::Vector2, double, double);
        void        attachFrame(Ogre::OverlayContainer*);

    private:
        Ogre::Overlay*           m_Overlay;
        std::vector<GUI::Frame*> m_Frames;
    };
}

#endif // __H_MAGE_UICONTEXT
```

**Mage/GUI/Frame.h**

```
#include <OGRE/OgreVector2.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreOverlayContainer.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreOverlayManager.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreString.h>

#include <Mage/GUI/UIContext.h>

#ifndef __H_MAGE_GUI_FRAME
#define __H_MAGE_GUI_FRAME

namespace Mage {
    namespace GUI {
        class Frame {
        public:
            Frame(Mage::UIContext*, Ogre::String, Ogre::Vector2, double, double);


        private:
            Ogre::OverlayContainer* m_Panel;
        };
    }
}

#endif // __H_MAGE_GUI_FRAME
```

I also included the WHOLE error log, but that just seems to be everything going down the gutter as this part fails. I haven't even touched that code and it has always compiled fine. Would it be needed to solve the problem, I'll include that as well; those are huge files though.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Mage3D, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 17/08/2012 19:43:22.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Mage3D.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  uicont.cpp
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): warning C4183: 'createFrame': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2065: 'Frame' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(23): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(18): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(19): error C2039: 'UIController' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(19): error C2065: 'UIController' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(19): error C2990: 'Ogre::Singleton' : non-class template has already been declared as a class template
1>          c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\ogre3d\include\ogre\ogresingleton.h(65) : see declaration of 'Ogre::Singleton'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(23): error C3413: 'Mage::UIContext::UIController' : invalid explicit instantiation
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(37): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontroller.h(38): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(4): error C2039: 'UIController' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(4): error C2039: 'UIController' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(4): error C2065: 'UIController' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(4): error C2955: 'Ogre::Singleton' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\ogre3d\include\ogre\ogresingleton.h(65) : see declaration of 'Ogre::Singleton'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(7): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(12): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(17): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(19): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(21): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(26): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(37): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(39): error C2653: 'UIController' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(39): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(55): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(67): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(73): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(74): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(75): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\uicont.cpp(75): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
1>  luagui.cpp
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2039: 'UIContext' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2039: 'UIContext' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'UIContext'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\luagui.cpp(76): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'lua_Number' to 'const Ogre::Real', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\luagui.cpp(76): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'lua_Number' to 'const Ogre::Real', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\luagui.cpp(77): error C2661: 'Mage::GUI::Frame::Frame' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
1>  frame.cpp
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2039: 'UIContext' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2039: 'UIContext' : is not a member of 'Mage'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'UIContext'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\gui\frame.cpp(4): error C2511: 'Mage::GUI::Frame::Frame(Mage::UIContext *,Ogre::String,Ogre::Vector2,double,double)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Mage::GUI::Frame'
1>          c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(16) : see declaration of 'Mage::GUI::Frame'
1>  context.cpp
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(21): warning C4183: 'createFrame': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2653: 'GUI' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2065: 'Frame' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(26): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\uicontext.h(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(18): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(23): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\mage3d\include\mage\gui\frame.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\ogre3d\include\ogre\ogrepixelformat.h(34): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mage3d\ogre3d\include\ogre\ogrepixelformat.h(43): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
... snip, just more of these errors ...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:11.44
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Well I don't know anymore. Hopefully you guys at **StackOverflow** can help me out as you always do. You people see everything I swear, and that's why I love you so.

Comment: ps: I know that the header files include themselves, I fixed that. Doesn't change or solve the problem.

Comment: Never mind, sorted it... adding prototypes of my classes before the includes seems to fix it. I realized this later.

Comment: Seems strange to have your #include guards so down in the file and not near the top.

Comment: I generally prefer to not have the includes inside the header guard, which shouldn't matter assuming every header has it's own header too.

Comment: But why process #includes when it isn't necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mage/GUI/UIContext.h you included "Mage/GUI/Frame.h" and after that in Mage/GUI/Frame.h you included "Mage/GUI/UIContext.h".

This is the reason why you get those errors.You should at least change one of those includes and it should be fine.

Comment: That wasn't the reason, the reason was a missing prototype.

Comment: Adding a header guard didn't solve the problem though, I had to define class prototypes. I'm still going to accept your answer, cause you were at least partially right.

Comment: I had similar problem in `A.h` I included `B.h` and in `B.h` I included `A.h`. I removed one of `#include` and problem has gone. `A.h` depends on `B.h` than I removed `#include "A.h"` in `B.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: a method of UIContext was looking for the class Mage::GUI::Frame, which did not exist. The constructor for the Frame class was looking for UIContext, which didn't exist either. Adding a prototype of the class before including the headers resolved that.

Comment: That just hides the problem. The other answer has the correct diagnostic.